# Константный массив чисел в C++

Tags: c++

Как в C++ создать константный массив чисел с символьными индексами, например, от 'a' до 'f'? Желательно попроще. :) То есть в Delphi было бы так

```
a : array['a'..'f'] of longint = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дополню ответ данный [@cy6erGn0m](/users/335/cy6ergn0m)

```
enum { RESULT_ERROR; }

int start;
int end;

int* makeArray( char first, char second) {
    start = (int)first; 
    end = (int)second;
    return new int[second-first+1];
}

int get( int *array, char ch){
    int index = (int)ch;
    if (first > index || index > end)
         return RESULT_ERROR;
    return  array[index-first];
}
```

Comment: Вот только RESULT_ERROR может совпасть по значнию с чем-нибудь лежащим в массиве. Думаю, это слишком опасно. Надо либо падать совсем, либо кидать C++-ное исключение.

Answer (score 6):

Если прямо ваш пример, то никакой массив не нужен. Просто вместо a[idx] надо (idx - 'a')

Если же вам правда надо ассоциировать символы с числами, то будет что-то наподобие такого:

```
const int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
const char a_max_idx = 'a' + sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);

int get(char idx) {
        if (idx < 'a' || idx >= a_max_idx)
               die(".....");

        return a[idx - 'a'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать std::map. Например, что-то в духе [такого](http://boost-sandbox.sourceforge.net/libs/xpressive/doc/html/boost_xpressive/user_s_guide/symbol_tables_and_attributes.html). Плюсом является компактность кода и хранения в памяти в случае, если требуется какое-то не непрерывное подмножество ASCII или Unicode. Заодно легко переделать на строчки.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum abc {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, v, w, x, y, z};
int name[j];

int main(){
    name[f]=2;
    cout << name[f] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Если я вас правильно понял. Этот вариант работает, но он не удобен, вам будет проще пользоваться обычным индексом name[3], да и программа работать быстрее будет.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с камрадом gecube. Для этого лучше всего подходит std:map.
Конечно, инициализировать его также компактно и элегантно не получится.

На будущее для вопросов по контейнерам рекомендую: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

Comment: Хэш-таблица более общая, но она требует больше ресурсов. В данном случе, мапу лучше не использовать.

Comment: Хм, почему лучше не использовать?

Comment: Потому что "нафига". Индексация вычисляется напрямую без всяких хэш-функций.

Comment: Потому что мапа намного дороже и медленнее, чем простая индексация